# nltk.pos_tag behaves inconsistently on specific words

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm using nltk.pos_tag() on a list of unique words. Some words however get different tags on reruns. For example: 
"bighorn" was tagged as NOUN, ADJECTIVE and VERB.

I don't want to enforce specific tagging but I like it to be consistent. Is there a way I could achieve this?

Comment: Can you post some code detailing what you tried?

Comment: `tagged_list = nltk.pos_tag(my_list)`

Comment: tagged_list = nltk.pos_tag(my_list, tagset='universal')

Comment: As far as I know, most pos-taggers are context specific and take into account the context also. The same word can be used as a noun and a verb in different contexts, and hence, it makes sense for the pos-tagger to label them differently.

Comment: Thanks Satwik, yes I agree with your point. I wonder if there is a way to enforce one of the many choices, when context is not available. 
I tried fixing the random seed and repeatedly tagging the same list. Neither of them worked.